# DDD: Adding entity to repository and handlig exceptions

Tags: entity-framework, exception, repository, domain-driven-design, logic

I am trying to model a simple domain by using DDD. Database layer is implemented by using Entity Framework and domain objects are POCO. Domain has User entity which has FirstName, LastName and Username properties. Accordingly, domain defines IRepository that handles repository for users.

Now one requirement in the domain logic is that no two users with same username can exist. So trying to add new user when another one with the same username already exist should throw an exception.

```
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
IRepository<User> users = unitOfWork.Users;

User user1 = new User() { Username = "jsmith", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
users.Add(user1);   
users.Save();       // ok, new user added to the underlying database

User user2 = new User() { Username = "jsmith", FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Smith" };
users.Add(user2); // exception here?
users.Save();     // or exception here?
```

This is an example of the code that should go into the WPF application that adds new user. Here, UnitOfWork encapsulates Entity Framework's DbContext object.

My question is how and where should I enforce this domain rule? Should exception be thrown when trying to add user into repository or rather when Save() method is called? Should I maybe create Domain Service for adding new users and then handle all domain logic rules there?

Also, what exception should I throw? Should I create some custom domain exception such as DuplicateUserException or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The db is the ultimate enforcer of that rule. Now, is this a multi user app? If so, then the most pragmatic way is to rely on the db , catch the sql exception and then throw a businessrule exception that will be redirected to the UI (i.e will trigger an error message).

You could verify that a name already exists at the domain level (via a Service is the most efficient way) but this can fail in a concurrent environment. However, it is an elegant and clean solution for a single user app. And by single user app I mean that ALL the app will serve one user at a time. If you have a WPF client and a web service, that's a multi user app.

Your best bet is to let the persistence (in this case the db) handle this rule, because it's the repo's responsibility to ensure that there are no duplicate names (the repository is not a dumb bucket, it's the manager of persistence) and it solves the concurrency problem as well.

Note that I haven't mentioned EF, because it doesn't matter the way you communicate with the db. If tomorrow you'll switch to Azure db, the solution is still the same, only specific parts of implementation will be different.

Comment: Yes this is a multi-user app in a sense that there will be WPF and ASP.NET MVC3 frontends that can be used at the same time by different users. So we are basically enforcing domain rules by persistence layer, if I understood it correctly? Should I then put common code for adding new user in some kind of service, rather than copy-paste code I wrote above in multiple places? If so, where should that service go and is that application or domain or infrastructure service? Sorry for additional questions but you really did help me improve my understanding!

Comment: Firstly, your whole app enforces the business rules, as you build the app to solve a business problem in the end. Now, that particular requierement is enforced at the repository level (via db constraint). Other reqs are more suitable in other places, the tricky part in DDD is that there are noe hard rules, only guidelines, the rest is up to you. I'd put the new user in the domain then send the object to the repo to be persisted. Simple validation can be done at UI or controller level, more rules at the domain level and finally the uniqueness constraint at the persistence level

Answer (score 2):

The best luck I've had is with using a custom initializer and specifying the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the database using `ExecuteSqlCommand` like so:

```
public class MyInitializer
  : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
  // Or whichever base class you want to use. DropCreateDatabaseAlways<>,
  // MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<>, etc. or even IDatabaseInitializer<>
{
  public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
  {
    // other initialization
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Users" +
                                       "ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Users_Username " +
                                       "UNIQUE(Username)");
  }
}
```

Which keeps the logic database bound. You cans also implement `EntityTypeConfiguration<User>` and perform a check on the `Validate` method, but you'd be pinging the database every validation just to check it.

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar with EF, could you please explain your code? Is this E-SQl query in your example used in fluent API for Code First?